# The current display adapter does not meet the emulator requirements to run XNA Framework applications

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna-4.0

hi *
I create a Windows Phone Game (4.0) application in Visual Studio 2010 and Win7. My application build successfully but when run it, throw an error that says:

"The current display adapter does not meet the emulator requirements to run XNA Framework applications."

What should I do, to remove this error?

Comment: Have you gone through this link:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/fa447c95-496e-431d-88a7-b0a76d177c92

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a DirectX 10 compatible video card.  If your card is compatible, you should make sure you have the latest driver for it.

Make sure your windows installation is up to date as well.

You can check to see if your card is compatible by using this software: [DirectX Caps Viewer Tool](https://web.archive.org/web/20111129124806/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee417852(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your thread. Followed the links ...
Ended up downloading the latest DirectX Version Dated: 11/30/2010.
It cleared up the error message.
Given the time that past this may not be of any help, as you've probably already worked around it.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2da43d38-db71-4c1b-bc6a-9b6652cd92a3&displayLang=en

Version:9.29.1973
Date Published:11/30/2010