# XNA Framework application requirements

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm using Windows 7 (all latest updates installed), and currently have DirectX 11 installed (according to dxdiag).

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff472340(VS.92).aspx and I can successfully compile the code (Build Solution produces no errors). The emulator starts successfully showing on IE icon on the main screen.

When I try to "Start Debugging" I get an error "**The current display adapter does not meet the emulator requirements to run XNA Framework applications.**"

I've read [The current display adapter does not meet the emulator requirements to run XNA Framework applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023424/) but it seems that all discussion in the links provided in that thread are for Windows Vista.

Please suggest what I can do. I'll be glad to provide more information if needed. Thanks!

Comment: If you saw my answer before I deleted it, it turns out to be wrong. I was thinking of [this issue](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4262/error-on-new-xna-4-0-game-project-no-suitable-graphics-card-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your display driver also needs to be WDDM1.1 compliant per the system requirements.

Search for WDDM in the text output of DXDiag.

Display driver update may be an option, if not replace adapter with compliant card.

Comment: I am WDDM1.0. I'm using NVIDIA GeForce Go 7300 (my laptop). I've updated all possible drivers, even got some from guru3d. Still nothing makes the model 1.1. Does this mean I cannot develop apps on this laptop?

Comment: For XNA dev on WP7 it's a hard requirement. You'll be able to run Silverlight apps, but may have performance issues with some features due to absence of hardware acceleration. You can add display adapters to some laptops.